# The partial view '/Views/Shared/ ... was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

In an ASP.Net mvc cshtml page I have the following code that calls 4 partial views located in my folder:

```
<div id="accordion">
     <h3 style="padding-left: 50px">Instructions</h3>
        <div>@Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml", null)</div>

    <h3 style="padding-left: 50px">Projects by  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</h3>
        <div>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_research.cshtml", Model.Proposalsvm)</div>
   <h3 style="padding-left: 50px">  Publications</h3>
        <div>  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_publications.cshtml", Model.Pubs)</div>
    <h3 style="padding-left: 50px">  Patents</h3>
        <div>   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_patents.cshtml", Model.Patents)</div>
    <h3 style="padding-left: 50px">Training</h3>
        <div>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Student.cshtml", Model.Students)</div>
    </div>
```

All the views are located in my Shared folder and the spelling is correct.  When I run the code from my local machine all the partial views are rendered.  When I deploy the code to my production machine, the last three partial views are rendered if I comment out the first one. If I don't I get the following error:

```
The partial view '/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml

Source Error: 
line 19:        <div id="accordion">
Line 20:          <h3 style="padding-left: 50px">Instructions</h3>
Line 21:             <div>@Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml", null)</div>
Line 22:             
Line 23:         <h3 style="padding-left: 50px">Projects by  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</h3>

Source File: d:\WebSite\BUD\Views\PUBLICATIONS_forUD\BARDat40.cshtml    Line: 21 

Stack Trace: 
[InvalidOperationException: The partial view '/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml]
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.FindPartialView(ViewContext viewContext, String partialViewName, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +416
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   ASP._Page_Views_PUBLICATIONS_forUD_BARDat40_cshtml.Execute() in d:\WebSite\BUD\Views\PUBLICATIONS_forUD\BARDat40.cshtml:21
```

The partial view causing the problems contains only divs and has no model.  I tried the solutions from previous answers and none have worked.  (The build for the view is Content, I have erased are recreated the partial view, renamed the partial view, removed the null from the @Html.Partial, removed the cshtml from the view -- none of which has worked.)

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be

```
<div>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml", null)</div>
```

You missed the `~` tilda which indicated relative routes

Comment: He don't need the second parameter if it's null i think, true? <div>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_instruct.cshtml")</div>

Comment: NO he doesn't.. but it wont hurt. Since the default value is `null`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I stared at the code for 4 hours and didn't see that.

Comment: Sometimes looking for more complicated bug for hours means you miss the very simple ones. Please consider accepting my answer if you can. Happy programming. (Take a break sometimes, then problems become very easy to spot after resting)